Простоя сортировка для получения пользователей
Подскажите, почему при простой сортировке пользователей по дате я получаю пустой ответ.
https://github.com/Lamantine0/WepApiProject


    @app.get("/sort_user_date/")
    async def sort_user_date(user_sort_by: date):

        with settings_db.Create_session() as db:

            sort_user = db.query(Table_user).filter(Table_user.created_at == user_sort_by)

        return sort_user
                  





как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Ваш код не соответствует репозиторию, пожалуйста, обновите до необходимого и опишите ваши результаты по реализации других методов вывода

Если нужно отсортировать то:
results = db.query(Users.username, Users.created_at).order_by(Users.created_at).all()

for user in results:
    print(user.username, user.created_at)

Если нужно отфильтровать по дате равной переменной user_sort_by
db.query(Users.username).filter(Users.created_at == user_sort_by)

